# How to Preserve/Protect Certain Fields in Edit in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In an Edit action in ASP.NET MVC, certain fields can be hidden from user with HiddenFieldFor. However this doesn't protect the fields (such as ID, data creation date) from being edited.

For example, a model Student has fields Id, Name and Birthday. I like to allow users to update the Name, but not Id nor Birthday.

For an Edit action like this

```
public ActionResult Edit(Student student)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(student);
}
```

How can I prevent Id and Birthday from being edited? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use a view model which contains only the properties that you want to be edited:

```
public class EditStudentViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Edit(StudentViewModel student)
{
    ...
}
```

Another technique which **I don't recommend** is to exclude certain properties from binding:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude = "Id,Birthday")]Student student)
{
    ...
}
```

or include:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Name")]Student student)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: How come I forgot View Model. What are you saying is that I should have a view model based on the Student model, and use that in the Edit view/action?

Comment: @Jim, yeah, how could you? Really. The most fundamental notion in ASP.NET MVC that solves all problems :-) Yes, you should have a view model which is specifically designed for the Edit action. It should contain only the properties that you are interested into. Then you should map between the view model and the model model to perform the update. [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) is a really great tool for this job.

Comment: Thanks! I will check out AutoMapper. Why you don't recommend excluding certain properties?

Comment: @Jim, because tomorrow you (or some other developer on the team) will add a new property to the domain model and will forget to add it to the controller action's `[Bind]` attribute and you will get very bad surprises. It's called `mass assignment` attack and it basically sets fields in your database that are never supposed to be set. Just think of the consequences if there was an IsAdmin field to your domain model => catastrophic. Suffice to forge an HTTP request with the `IsAdmin=true` in it and the student will become administrator.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I ended up making my own mapping between model and view model.

Comment: What about Include then? It seems it won't have the problem as it's a white-list approach?

Comment: @Jim, yeah, Include is safer, but still you will have to do the change in 2 places: add a property on your domain and modify your controller action or all of a sudden the new property will not be taken into account when doing the binding. Doing the same job at two different places seems like a bad design to me.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Making ViewModels for every Model could be problematic in some big projects. Question: Since we are generating the form with server code, isn't there a way to generate a hash or something with the fields created and validate that hash in the form POST?

Comment: @EduardoMolteni, I don't know and I don't want to know since I always use view models and I don't have such problems. You could reinvent whatever mechanisms you feel comfortable with in your application if you don't want to use view models. I cannot recommend you nor give you any ideas as for me that's bad design.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632427/im-trying-to-preserve-protect-certain-fields-in-a-view-model For anyone getting stuck implementing like I did

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have to have the properties in your Model so that in View you can use them to render useful information e.g. an ActionLink with ID or some readonly Text.

In this case you can define your model with an explicit binding:

```
[Bind(Include = "Name")]
public class Student
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    int Name { get; set; }
    DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

This way when updating your model, if the user submits an extra Id it will not be bound.

Another idea I like is having your model know its bindings per scenario and have them compiler validated:

```
public class ModelExpression<T>
{
    public string GetExpressionText<TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression)
    {
        return ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    }
}

public class Student
{
    public static string[] EditBinding = GetEditBinding().ToArray();

    int Id { get; set; }
    int Name { get; set; }
    DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    static IEnumerable<string> GetEditBinding()
    {
        ModelExpression<Student> modelExpression = new ModelExpression<Student>();
        yield return modelExpression.GetExpressionText(s => s.Name);
    }
}
```

This way in your Action when calling TryUpdateModel you can pass this information.