# I'm trying to Preserve/Protect certain fields in a View Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to implement the solution [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7546290/947978), but once I replace my "Users" class with the "EditUserViewModel" class (the one that has less fields than the Users class) and once I get to this line

```
db.Entry(users).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

in this code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(EditUserViewModel users)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(users).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(users);
    }
```

I get the error

```
The entity type EditUserViewModel is not part of the model for the current context.
```

Now I'm guessing this error is because my DBContext uses the Users class and not the EditUserViewModel class. Am I missing a step or is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Can you please post `EditUserViewModel` and `User` classes?

Comment: @Omar posted the classes

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you are missing the mapping between your new view model and the corresponding domain model. Your business layer probably can't (and usually shouldn't) know how to directly persist your view models.

Comment: Removed classes b/c I have answer and don't see classes as relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge the data from your MV to your Model class.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var existingUser = db.Users.Single(p => /* query to find your user */);

    existingUser.From = user.From;
    existingUser.CC = user.CC;
    // etc.

    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```