# How can I prevent an Entity Framework object's properties from being altered in a default edit action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

This is the default edit/update action generated by MVC 4:

```
// POST: /User/Edit/5
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,FirstName,LastName,EmailAddress,Company")] User user)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(user);
}
```

There are a few properties not listed here that I have removed from the edit view:

- HashedPassword
- IsGlobalAdmin

Those values become NULL every time I save this form. What do I need to change to prevent this?

Comment: Well, what should they become?

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson They should be unchanged. I don't want those values to be editable here.

Comment: The _right_ way is to use a ViewModel and deal with the properties when mapping to the Model.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546284/how-to-preserve-protect-certain-fields-in-edit-in-asp-net-mvc) for a similar question and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current changes to the Entity State marks all of the columns to be updated. I would change the code to this:

```cs
public ActionResult Edit(User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        User saveUser = new User { ID = user.ID }
        db.Attach(saveUser);
        saveUser.FirstName = user.FirstName
        saveUser.LastName = user.LastName
        saveUser.EmailAddress = user.EmailAddress;
        saveUser.Company = user.Company;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(user);
}
```

Every change to `saveUser` after `db.Attach(saveUser)` is called is tracked for updating. (This will give a SQL exception if the user isn't in the database, though.)

Comment: That's the idea. You have to match up the Primary Key before you attach it. (hence the `ID = User.ID` line)

Comment: Here's some [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx) on all of this.

Comment: i mean it will only updated the columns we are setting the null one will not be updated is this what you mean??

Comment: Correct. Only the changes to `saveUser` are tracked by entity framework. (that's what Attaching means)

Answer (score 0):

They will be posted null if you will remove them from the view, instead of that make  hidden fields for them using `Html.HiddenFor()` helper so that they are posted in form as hidden but user will not be able to edit them:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.HashedPassword)
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.IsGlobalAdmin)
```

Comment: That will make them visible to the client (and editable through a `POST`)

Comment: any other way available??

Comment: Because the ViewModel determines which fields are editable and passes _only those fields_ back to the model.  It's not a simple change but it's the _safest_.

Comment: Can you post the solution as answer?

Comment: No because it's a duplicate of [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7546290/1081897)

Comment: yeahs Thanks @DStanley got understood that..:)